# Snackbar cannot resolve method make

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, android-design-library

I am having a issue trying to put a snackbar working, i think it has something to do with my build gradle, i could import the snackbar into my activity but then this happens:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcbRA.png)

my gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.afcosta.inesctec.pt.android"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

i tried to change the compile versions of the design but then i need to change the appcombat too and that gives me some errors, any help?

Comment: You should pass your `view` instead of `Register.this`

Comment: pass my view? how?

Comment: The id of your view (content).

Comment: put this inside: R.layout.activity_register and get this error: cannot resolve method 'make(int,java.lang.String,int)

Comment: Try out below answers

Answer (score 1):

**Try this my friend**

```
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
    .make(coordinatorLayout, "Message is deleted", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
    .setAction("UNDO", new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar snackbar1 = Snackbar.make(coordinatorLayout, "Message is restored!", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
            snackbar1.show();
        }
    });
```

snackbar.show();

Answer (score 0):

```
build.gradle

    dependencies 
    {
       compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
           compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
    }


      Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                    .make(coordinatorLayout, "Message is deleted", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("UNDO", new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            Snackbar snackbar1 = Snackbar.make(coordinatorLayout, "Message is restored!", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
                            snackbar1.show();
                        }
                    });


        snackbar.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your activity's parent layout as view.

```
Snackbar.make(View view, CharSequence text, int duration)
```

Register.this won't work in the case of snackbar but would work in the case of a Toast because makeText requires context.

```
Toast.makeText(Context context, CharSequence text, int duration)
```

Comment: put this inside: R.layout.activity_register and get this error: cannot resolve method 'make(int,java.lang.String,int)

Answer (score 0):

Just Change Like this

```
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(Register.java,"ola",Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
```

Replace with this

```
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(R.id.main,"ola",Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
```

Assign your layout id like this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

</LinearLayout
```

It will help you...

Comment: put this inside: R.layout.activity_register and get this error: cannot resolve method 'make(int,java.lang.String,int)

Comment: See my Updated answer and make some changes